# How do I get systemctl to run mysql after installing with dnf?

Tags: mysql, fedora, systemctl

I installed mysql using `sudo dnf install community-mysql`
When I type `which mysql` I get /user/bin/mysql

When I try to run it using systemctl start mysql or mysqld or mysql80 it doesn't recognize any of those services, and when I use systemctl --type=service mysql isn't listed.

I'm a new Linux user (using Fedora 39).  What am I missing?  It said installatino was complete, but how on earth do I get it running?  Complete newbie to linux (this is day 2).  Jumping in feet first.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 reached End of Life in October 2023. MariaDB is a natural choice as it maintains compatibility with MySQL protocols, doesn’t require any changes to your application and doesn’t require your teams to learn new skills – making migration a breeze

Answer (score 2):

Here's the looking I did, and this answer (I didn't test) is probably correct and at least will teach you how to look in the general sense and take you to the next step.

```
sudo dnf search community-mysql
```

and it shows `community-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries`, but you don't usually run "client programs" on startup with systemctl, so you're looking for a server or daemon. That same dnf search also lists `community-mysql-server.x86_64 : The MySQL server and related files`

so you'll need to install that "server" package (I checked, it contains a /usr/sbin/mysqld where the "d" indicates a daemon)

```
sudo dnf install community-mysql-server 
sudo systemctl enable mysqld 
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

You only need the "start" command this first time; in the future, the enable will automatically start the daemon when you reboot. In some other case like this, if systemctl can't find the "mysqld" field, the service could have a different name. You showed you know how to search for services, I tend to go lower level and find all the possible service files with something like

```
locate -ri \\.service$ | less
```

Back to the beginning, checking for a "daemon" file is a good general starting place when you're trying to install a server. For example the command

```
sudo dnf provides */mysqld
```

would directly show you packages that contain the mysqld daemon. the */ means look in any directory because it could be in /usr/bin or /usr/sbin or /bin or /sbin

I've used fedora a long time (since it was called red hat:) but I don't use mysql, that's why I'm able to suggest the right answer but I didn't test it.